# Unrecognized selector sent to class + uncaught exception of type NSException / NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift

I'm still crashing my app with the UIBarButtonItem:
I've tried 3 several ways I found here in previous topics, and none of them have worked out. I'm new to Swift and I really don't know what could be causing the problem, before it worked just fine...

The 3 several ways I tried, which 1 is the original code:

1)
`let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: MyViewController.self, action: #selector(onBtnDoneTap))`

`@objc private func onBtnDoneTap() { code to be executed on tap... }`

2)
`let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: MyViewController.self, action: #selector(onBtnDoneTap(sender:)))`

`@objc private func onBtnDoneTap(sender: UIBarButtonItem) { code to be executed on tap... }`

3)
`let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: MyViewController.self, action: #selector(onBtnDoneTap(_:)))`

`@objc private func onBtnDoneTap(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) { code to be executed on tap... }`

All crashed on the following line:

`UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(appDelegateClass))`

> **Thread 1: "+[App.MyViewController onBtnDoneTap]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1051c38b0"**

With the following errors in the output window:

`[13122:7952368] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[App.MyViewController onBtnDoneTap]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1051c38b0'`

`libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[App.MyViewController onBtnDoneTap]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1051c38b0' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)`

Thanks for your help!

Changing the target to "self", causes a warning but the app doesn't explote anymore, I can live with the warnings as long it doesn't explote:

`class MyViewController: UIViewController { let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onBtnDoneTap)) }`

Which now here appears the warning
'self' refers to the method ‘MyViewController.self', which may be unexpected

`extension MyViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
@objc private func onBtnDoneTap() {
    self.dummyTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    let selectedLanguage = self.selectedItem?.Languages?
    ...
}
```

}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `MyViewController.self` as the action target, use `self`:

```swift
let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onBtnDoneTap))
```

This means that the target is not the *class* `MyViewController` but a specific `MyViewController` *instance*.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but it only gives me the warning: `'self' refers to the method 'MyViewController.self', which may be unexpected.`

Comment: Would you add more code to your post? I’ll need to see the nesting to understand what’s going on.

Comment: Okay, I see the reason for the warning in the code you add: When the object is created, its member variables (like `btnDone`) may be created before `self`. So when you use `self` to initialize `btnDone`, it may not exist yet.

Comment: To solve that, just add replace `let btnDone` with `lazy var btnDone`.